# find the smallest integer in a balanced BST

Tags: binary-search-tree

The integers are stored in the key or node of the balanced BST?
If it is was the key, then what is the node storing?

If a balanced BST's nodes are storing integers, does the smallest keys corr. to smallest nodes?

Answer (score 0):

When you are asked to find the smallest value in a BST, then it is about *keys*. A BST structure does not help you find other data that might be stored with the keys. The power that a BST offers, is when you need to find data by *key*.

A BST node can store only a key, or can store a key and related data. For instance it can store a pair (key, value) where both are integers. When you get a code challenge that relates to a BST, you'll know what type of data is stored in it.

In a BST the node with the smallest key is stored in the left-most leaf of that tree. So starting from the root you go left for as long as you can until you find a node that has no left child. That is the node that has the smallest key.